# PowerShell on CSV file - looking for string depending on string

Tags: string, powershell, csv

I need your help regarding PowerShell programming on CSV file.

I've made some searches but cannot find what I'm looking for (or perhaps I don't know the technical terms). Basically, I have an Excel workbook with large amount of data (more or less 38 columns x 350.000 rows), and there are a couple of formulas that take hours to calculate.

I was first wondering if PowerShell could speed up a bit the calculation compared to Excel. The calculations taking most of my time are in fact not that complex (at least at first glance). My data is more or less constructed like this:

```
Ref      Title
-----    --------------------------
A/001    "free_text"
A/002    "free_text A/001 free_text"
...      ...
A/005    "free_text A/004 free_text"
A/006    "free_text"
B/001    "free_text" 
B/002    "free_text"
C/001    "free_text"
C/002    "free_text"
...
C/050    "free_text C/047 free_text"
...      ...
C/103    "free_text"
D/001    "free_text"
D/002    "free_text D/001 free_text"
...      ....
```

Basically the data is as follows:

1. the *Ref* field contains unique values, in `{letter}/{incremental value}` format.
2. In some rows, the *Title* field may call up one of the *Ref* data. For example, in line 2, the *Title* calls for the A/001 *Ref*. In the last row, the *Title* calls for the D/001 *Ref*, etc.
3. There is no logic pattern defining when this ref could be called up in a title. This is random.

However, what I'm 100% sure of is the following:

1. The *Ref* called in the *Title* is always belonging to the same `{letter}` block. For example: the string 'C/047' in the *Title* field can only be found in the block where the *Ref* `{letter}` is C.
2. The *Ref* called in the *Title* will always be located 'after' (or in a lower row) than the *Ref* it refers to. In other words, I cannot have a line with following pattern:

   ```
   Ref             Title
   ------------    -----------------------------------------
   {letter/i}      {free_text {letter/j} free_text} with j<i
   ```

   → This is not possible.
   → j is always > i

I've used these characteristics in Excel to minimize my lookup arrays. But it still takes an hour to calculate everything.

I've therefore looked into PowerShell, and started to 'play' a bit with the CSV, and looping with the `ForEach-Object` hoping I would have quicker results. Up to now I basically ended-up looping twice on my CSV file.

```
$CSV1 = myfile.csv
$CSV2 = myfile.csv

$CSV1 | ForEach-Object {
    # find Title
    $TitSearch = $_.$Ref
    $CSV2 | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.$Title -eq $TitSearch) {
            myinstructions
        }
    }
}
```

It works but it's really really really long. So I then tried the following instead of using the `$CSV2 | ForEach...`:

```
$CSV | where {$_.$Title -eq $TitleSearch} | % $Ref
```

In either case, it's too long and not efficient at all. Additionally with these 2 solutions, I'm not using above characteristics which could reduce the lookup array and as already stated, it seems I end up looping twice on the CSV file from its beginning up to the end.

Questions:

1. Is there a leaner way to do this?
2. Am I wasting my time with PowerShell?
3. I though about creating 1 file per *Ref* `{letter}` block (1 file for block A, 1 for B, etc...). However I have about 50.000 blocks to create. Or create them one by one, carry out the analysis, put the results in a new file, and delete them. Would that be quicker?

Note: this is for work, to be used by other colleagues, and Excel and PowerShell are really the only softwares we may use. I know VBA but ok... At the end I'm curious about how and if this can be solved in a simple manner using PowerShell.

Comment: It might be quite a bit easier if you use Doug Finke's import excel https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/5.3.4 It may make it easier for you

Comment: For one thing, the first sample code snippet you posted cannot possibly work. A statement `$CSV1 = myfile.csv` would try to execute `myfile.csv` (i.e. open the file with the default handler), then assign the output of the command (most likely nothing) to the variable. Also, `$Title` in `$_.$Title -eq $TitSearch` is undefined. Please make sure you always post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're facing.

Comment: Speaking of which, what problem *are* you facing anyway? It's not clear to me what your code is *supposed* to do. Do you want to identify records where the reference in the *Title* field has a different letter or an index less then what is in the corresponding *Ref* field?

Comment: Your problem is analogous to the problem that is solved by the symbol table in a one pass compiler.  User defined symbols are usually variables, but there are other kinds of symbols as well.  However, your algorithm results in a sweep  through the data for every reference to a previous line of data.  If you have 350.000 lines, and about 1000 references, that means scanning  350.000.000 lines of data.  That's going to take hours, in any language.  You need a better algorithm.

Comment: In the second line of your example, I is equal to 002 and J is equal to 001, if I'm reading you right.  That means that J < I.  This seems to violate your second constraint.  Am I reading you wrong?

Comment: If you are dealing with large arrays, don't use pipelines, they are slow. Just use foreach loop, like foreach ($row in $rows) { <#do smth #> }

Comment: @MikeTwc That statement is at least misleading, although not entirely wrong. A `foreach` loop provides better performance if (and only if) your data are small enough to fit into memory. For processing large amounts of data pipelining is essential, because it prevents memory exhaustion.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your base algorithm  do N^2 iteration (~120 billion). There is a standard way to make it efficient - you need to build a hashtable first. Hashtable is a key/value storage, and look up is pretty much instantaneous, so algorithm's time complexity will become ~N. 
Powershell has built-in data type for that. In your case the key would be ref, and the value an array of cell data (assuming your table is smth like: ref, title, col1, ..., colN)

```
$hash = @{}
foreach($row in $table} {$hash.Add($row.ref, @($row.title, $row.col1, ...)}
#it will take 350K steps to generate it
#then you can iterate over it again
foreach($key in $hash.Keys) { 
 $key # access current ref
 $rowData = $hash.$key # access to current row elements (by index)
 $refRowData = $hash[$rowData[$j]] # lookup from other rows, assuming lookup reference is in some column
}
```

So it's a general idea how to solve the time issue. To be honest I don't believe you need to recreate a wheel and code it yourself. What you need is a relational database. Since you have excel, you should have MS ACCESS too. Just import your data in there, make ref and title an index, then all you need to do is self join. MS Access suck, but I'm sure it will handle 350K row just fine. 
Ideally you'd need to get a database on some corporate MSSQL server (open a ticket, talk to your manger, etc). It will calculate all that in seconds, and then you can link the output to a spreadsheet as well.